# PHP read csv field contain new line in the field

Tags: php, csv, newline

Let's see I have this in csv string (got it from cURL output):

```
"name";"gender";"address";"phone";\n
"John Doe"; "Male"; "Broke Street\n No. 69 South Pole";"911";\n
```

Something like that, I use explode to get to line by line, however there is a field that also use \n for new line thus mess up my array index. How can I workaround this, any idea?

Comment: Edited the actual csv content I got which has double quote on field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atm Im using str_replace to replace '";\n' to '";#n' or to something else you like and use explode to split #n delimiter to get every row.

I guess thats what works for me right now.

Answer (score 2):

That's a badly generated/corrupted .csv, in that case. If a field contains line breaks, then it should be surrounded by `"` so the csv parser can tell a line-break-to-start-new-record apart from line-break-inside-a-field-just-to-make-a-new-line apart.

Fix whatever's generating the csv, rather than trying to handle the garbage it's spitting out.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the csv field is actually enveloped by double quotes, which I remove it with str_replace thus it leaves with that clean data atm. I will edit my post. So what csv parser should I use, the php str_getcsv?

Comment: that means you're corrupting the csv yourself. stop massaging the data before it's been parsed.

Comment: The reason because it works if the value has no containing new line or delimiter. So its as easy as using str_replace and explode to get the job done. Now if you are referring to str_getcsv($output,"\n",'"') or without enclosure param, the parser still fail to recognize the \n inside the field is not for new row line.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, that's a malformed csv.

Actually you may use preg_match_all to parse that file, without caring whether it's a csv or not.

eg: preg_match('#([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+)\s?#', $csv_file_content, $matches);